# What is the highest suitable integer for rolling modulo hasing?

Tags: algorithm, hash, modulo, rabin-karp

Given an algorithm that uses an modulo hash function, meaning big numbers bigger than a certain given integer will "wrap around" so the result is always in between 0 and the given integer.
For example the [Rabin-Karp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) needs a rolling hash, with a clever modulo.
What is the highest modulo possible? And why is that?

Comment: There is no highest modulo possible. In general, the bigger the modulo the better the hash, but the slower it is to compute.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a limit? Have you ever considered a 32-bit integer, with modulo 2^(31)-1? This will not work, because any sufficient large enough integer multiplication, will cause the integer to overflow, before you can take the modulo.

Answer (score -1):

To answer this question it is important to check what the "highest-impact" operation is between to modulo calls. This means that if you expect a number optimally to be multiplied with 97*101=9797, you have to devide 2^(32) by 9797 (from the Rabin-Karp example), and then look for the nearest prime in this area. If you for instance add 2600 to an integer, you have to substract 2600 from 2^(32). If you square a given number, you have to take the squareroot from 2^(32), etc.

This will then prevent that any overflow will happen after an operation and before the modulo call. Therefore always keeping the hashed number in between 0 and the selected prime.

Because you have selected a (high) prime, the number of hash collisions is as low as possible.